# Update Manager fails to download package files

Tags: updates

How can I resolve this issue? Thank you!

```
Failed to fetch h ttp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-gnome_0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Failed to fetch h ttp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-plugins-default_0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Failed to fetch h ttp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/libdecoration0_0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-core_0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz_0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try updating through 'Terminal'. Open the Dash, open 'Terminal' then type:

sudo apt-get update

Click Enter, type your system password and wait for it to finish. This may fix your problem, once it's finished updating, try the graphical update manager again to see if it's fixed.

If that fails then you may need to repair your dpkg database, you can do this with the following command in 'Terminal':

sudo dpkg --configure -a